# No such column for attribute in a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes, associations, join

I'm trying to create an app where a user chooses volunteers to complete their task. The way that `volunteers` are considered `participants` is through the `selected` boolean attribute placed on the `TaskVolunteer` join table. Unfortunately when I try to find the participants of a particular class I get the following error:

```
task = Task.create
task.participants
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.selected
```

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :task_volunteers, as: :volunteer
  has_many :volunteered_tasks, through: :task_volunteers
end

class TaskVolunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
    # task_id, volunteer_id, selected (boolean)
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :volunteer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :volunteer_id
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    # owner_id
    has_many :task_volunteers
    has_many :volunteers, through: :task_volunteers, source: :volunteer
    has_many :participants, -> {where(selected: true)}, through: :task_volunteers, source: :volunteer

    belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by a faulty `foreign_key` option in TaskVolunteer.

```
 belongs_to :volunteer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :volunteer_id
```

`foreign_key` here refers to the column on the `users` table not on `tasks_volunteers`. You can just remove the foreign key option.

```
class TaskVolunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
    # task_id, volunteer_id, selected (boolean)
    belongs_to :task
    belongs_to :volunteer, class_name: "User"
end
```

**Added**

I have to say though by altering the naming a bit and using an enum to denote status you could cut the code and cognitive complexity quite dramatically.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations, foreign_key: :participant_id
  has_many :owned_tasks, class_name: "Task", as: :owner
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :participations
  has_many :participants, through: :participations, source: :participant
  # Dynamically generates relations such as 'selected_participants'
  Participation.statuses.keys.each do |status|
    has_many "#{status}_participants".to_sym,
             -> { where(participations: { status: status.to_sym }) },
             through: :participations,
             source: :participant
  end
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
  enum status: [:interested, :selected]
end
```

The enum macro gives you stuff like:

```
user.participations.selected
participation.selected?
```

Comment: Unfortunately still get the error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.selected`

Comment: Maybe `where('tasks_volunteers.selected' => true)`?

Comment: Here's what seemed to get it to work: leaving the foreign key in tact and writing the conditional as `-> {where('task_volunteers.selected' => true)}` (making `task_volunteers` singular).

Comment: Based on this code would you happen to know how to add participants to a task? When I tried creating a `TaskVolunteer`, setting its `selected` attribute to `true` and appending it to an instance of a task I still get an empty array when I use `task.volunteers` or `task.participants`

Comment: `user.tasks << task` `task.task_volunteers.where(volunteer: user).last.update(selected: true) `

Comment: Or just `TaskVolunteer.find_or_initialize(volunteer: user, task: task).update(selected: true)`

Comment: Great, both work. On a closing note do I need `has_many :volunteered_tasks, through: :task_volunteers`? The reason I ask is because if I were to do: `user.volunteered_tasks` I get the error: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "volunteered_task" or :volunteered_tasks in model TaskVolunteer. Try 'has_many :volunteered_tasks, :through => :task_volunteers, :source => <name>'. Is it one of task or volunteer?`

Comment: Yeah still need the relation to the join model when using has_many :through. I added an example of how you might alter the naming to make it less confusing (at least IMHO).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much for recommending this alternative solution.

Comment: Does `Participation.statuses.keys.each...` get written in the model or is it something that can be written in the console?

Comment: Well, its evaluated at class eval - so in order to use it from the console you would need to open up the Task class.

Comment: After experimenting with this code I found that I had to change the following association in my user model to get things to work: `has_many :owned_boosts, class_name: "Boost", foreign_key: :owner_id`

Comment: And if I could return to the class method for `Participation` in the `Task` model. How come its inside the task model instead of the participation model? I never knew that associations could be set in enumerables.

Comment: You mean the dynamic relations thing? Well it's in Task since it uses metaprogramming to add a bunch of relations (class methods) to Task. Its not really an enum thing either - it just happens to use the available statuses to generate relations.